# Minimum and maximum number of elements in intersection of sets.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a battle *70%* of the combatants lost one eye, *80%* an ear, *85%*  a leg, *75%* an arm, *x%* lost all four limbs.Then

- What is the minimum value of x?
- What is the maximum value of x?
- From van diagram I figured that the minimum value of x is 10%. But I am not satisfied with my version of explanation.

`

Comment: I think maximum will be 70%

Comment: wait does all 4 limbs mean losing 1 ear, 1 arm and 1 leg?

Comment: One eye, one ear, one leg and one arm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about max, because it's $\min(70\%,75\%,80\%,85\%)=70%$.

For the next question (which you were right as well) I find it easier to explain with numbers, say out of $100$.

The minimum intersection of $70$ and $75$ is $70-(100-75)=70-25=45$

The minimum intersection of $80$ and $85$ is $80-(100-85)=80-15=65$

The minimum intersection of $45$ and $65$ is... (hint: same way as the previous two) $10$.

Comment: So what's the generalization to this? `sum(SET) - (len(SET) - 1) * 100`? At least, that's what I inferred from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcT4ExbSYRI)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the general algorithm to determine the minimum is as follows (in Python)

```
def get_min_intersection (slices,total = 100):
    if sum(slices)- (len(slices)-1) * total >= 0:
        return sum(slices)- (len(slices)-1) * total
    else:
        return 0

# The minimum intersection of [70,80,75,85] out of 100 is 10
assert get_min_intersection([70,80,75,85]) == 10

# The minimum intersection of [90,60,80] out of 100 is 10 according to https://youtu.be/GcT4ExbSYRI?t=34
assert get_min_intersection([90,60,80]) == 30

# The minimum intersection of [30,35,32] out of 50 is 0 according to https://youtu.be/GcT4ExbSYRI?t=251
assert get_min_intersection( [30,35,32], 50) == 0

# The minimum intersection of [40,50,60] out of 100 is 0 according to https://www.handakafunda.com/set-theory-maximum-and-minimum-values/
assert(get_min_intersection( [40,50,60]) ==  0)
```

As @Joao said, the maximum intersection is the minimum of the elements in the set.